# How to get message delivery status using smack?

Tags: android, xmpp, kotlin, smack

Requesting for delivery status while sending message

```
 var message:Message = Message()
            message.addBody("EN",msg_text.text.toString())
            Log.i("Delivery Request id ",DeliveryReceiptRequest.addTo(message))

            Log.v("Chat Response msg ",chat.send(message).toString())
```

DeliveryReceiptListener

//delivery status recipient

```
var deliveryReceiptManager= DeliveryReceiptManager.getInstanceFor(connection)
        deliveryReceiptManager.autoReceiptMode = DeliveryReceiptManager.AutoReceiptMode.always
        deliveryReceiptManager.autoAddDeliveryReceiptRequests()
        deliveryReceiptManager.addReceiptReceivedListener { fromJid, toJid, receiptId, receipt ->

            Log.i("From jid ",fromJid.toString())
            Log.i("To jid ",toJid.toString())
            Log.i("Receipt id  ",receiptId.toString())
            Log.i("recipt ",receipt.toString())

        }
```

I am not able to get the delivery status i.e read/unread/msg received. How will I implement this?